# How sort a dict using the values of a list inside (two sequential criteria)

Tags: python

I need to sort this dict with two sequential criteria: "rank" descending, "fruit" ascending (in case of same ranking result).

The dict is structured in this way

```
'object':['fruit',rank]
```

For example I've:

```
myDict = {'item2': ['bananas', 3], 'item3': ['cocumbers', 11], 'item1': ['pinapples', 3], 'item4': ['pears', 3]}
```

My aim is to obtain this:

```
{'item3': ['cocumbers', 11], 'item2': ['bananas', 3],'item4': ['pears', 3], 'item1': ['pinapples', 3]}
```

with

```
sorted(myDict.items(), key=lambda (k, v): v[1], reverse=True)
```

I obtain only the correct sorting for rank but with no sorting order for the objects with the same ranking:

```
[('item3', ['cocumbers', 11]), ('item2', ['bananas', 3]), ('item1', ['pinapples', 3]), ('item4', ['pears', 3])]
```

How solve this in python 2.7?

Thank's

Comment: Dictionaries are not sequences, they cannot be sorted. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/python-sort-a-dictionary-by-value) for discussion.

Comment: @unwind: Incorrect. Dictionaries can be sorted, but the output can only be a list; I think you meant to say that they can't be sorted IN-PLACE

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sorted(myDict.items(), key=lambda (k, v): (-v[1],v[0]))`

should do the trick.  Since `rank` is an integer, we can easily make it sort descending by making the key function just return the negative value rather than needing the `reverse=True` keywords to `sorted`.  In the case of a tie, we fall back on the natural ordering of the strings.

This works because sequences in python sort lexicographically (`tuples` are a sequence type) -- Python compares elements from each sequence in order until one of the elements is non-equal which gives the ordering of your pair of sequences.

In the case where you can't easily replace `reverse=True` with a key function, you'll need to sort twice:

```
l1 = sorted(myDict.items(),key=lambda (k,v):v[0])
l1.sort(key=lambda (k,v):v[1],reverse=True)
```

This relies on the documented fact that a python sort must be stable.  In other words, the relative order of elements that are equal is the same before and after sorting.

Comment: Very elegant! I was going to define a comparator function to use with `sorted`'s `cmp` param

Comment: @inspectorG4dget -- I'd always advise against using `cmp`.  It's less efficient (the key function is guaranteed to be called once per object, `cmp` could be called multiple times) and (more importantly) `cmp` is gone in python3.x

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use [collections.OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#ordereddict-objects) to maintain order inside dicts.